# Where are certain Wordpress files that I want to programmatically edit?

Tags: wordpress

I have a simple perl script that via ftp uploads files to the server hosting our website. After I do that I have to login as a Wordpress admin and use the GUI to edit a page so that it reflects the new file I just uploaded. I want to programmatically edit that file to save a few steps, but I can't find the file. Are any Wordpress files sitting on the server? The file in question is basically a subpage of the main site.

Comment: Your question is confusing. What you mean by "but I can't find the file"? You can't find the file that you just uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the content of a page, then the content would be in the wp_posts table in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You will find all the files under wp-content/themes/default/ directory.

you should start editing header.php which is top area.
Edit index.php which is the middle part.
Edit sidebar.php which is the sidebar (Navigation area)
finally edit footer.php which is Bottom footer section.

I hope this will help.